# React conflict when consuming a local react library

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I have a Parent React App that consumes a module library which is also a React app. I used to have `react` and `react-dom` installed in the parent project and have them added as a `peerDependencies` in `package.json` in the modules library. But, now I need to install the two packages as `devDependencies` in the modules library.

This resulted in [Invalid Hook Error](https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html), which I narrowed down to the third point:

> you might have more than one copy of React in the same app

Parent App's `package.json`:

```
{
  // Other Deps..
  "modules-lib": "file:../libs/modules-lib/dist",
}
```

I've tried a couple of solutions from this [issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/13991), but things didn't work. I also tried linking `react` and `react-dom` using `npm link` from our modules library to the parent app and it actually worked.

I was wondering that why does the consumer of the modules library looks into its `node_modules` folder and why the two packages are being listed as `dependencies` and not `devDependencies` in the final build folder in `package.json`

Comment: `you might have more than one copy of React in the same app`, meaning it is probably not a good idea to try to load one react page into another one?

Comment: In the React official docs, they do state that its fine having independent React versions. In my case. both the parent app and the module library uses react v16.13.0